# UFW Firewall in Rescue Mode - do settings made there stay applied when Ubuntu 18.04 is rebooted to live mode? Mine don't seem to

Tags: 18.04, ufw, recovery-mode

Running Ubuntu 18.04. I have had trouble with `uwf` so I decided to reinstall and reset.

I have booted the VPS into rescue mode. Did the following mounting:

```
fdisk -l
mkdir /mnt/mydrive
mount dev/sdb1 /mnt/mydrive
cd /
mount -o remount,rw /
```

I then reinstalled `uwf`. After that I reset it to default `Deny incoming` and `Allow outgoing`.

Then, I went through and allowed the usual things like HTTP, HTTPS, SSH, and a few others including RDP.

Rebooted back to the live state and then ran `ss -ltn` and `iptables -l` to check the settings.

However nothing had changed, it was all as it was prior to my updates, showing the original issues I had.

My question is - should whatever I did within rescue mode with settings as described above, remain that way when I reboot back to the live server?

Or, Do I need to do all of the above via SSH in the live server state?

I might as well also ask, are there any ready made `iptables` than can just be copied in?

Comment: Can you be more specific than *"Did the usual mounting etc."*? Did you chroot into the installed system, or just mount specific filesystems?

Comment: Appreciate the reply. I'm not a Unix guy unfortunately just Windows as such not fluent with the processes. I didn't run chroot no, just mounting. I have updated the main post with more detail.